# react-horizontal-scrolling-menu Arrow not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use horizontal scroll in project using react-horizontal-scrolling-menu. Scroll is working, however `Arrow` feature is not working. I have used following code to test:

```js
import {Arrow } from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
const App= () =>{
    return(
        <Arrow disabled={true}>Left</Arrow>
    )
}
export default App
```

Getting the error: *Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

Can someone let me know the syntax for Arrow element and expected parameters?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the error message you're receiving is inaccurate?  For example, the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu) for this package doesn't list an exported component called "Arrow"; are you sure that this component even exists?

Comment: Well the more I look at this package, the less sure I am of what is going on.  I still see no evidence that there is an exported `Arrow` component, but I find the source code difficult to read, and honestly can't even get this package to work at all in my own project.  I'll let you know if I end up figuring it out for sure, though.

Comment: Even I am not sure. I am referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu documentation. If I don't import Arrow, it is giving error Arrow is not defined. Not sure from where do we need to import this Arrow component.

Comment: There is no `Arrow` component you'll need to create it yourself or you can take a look at [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-v2-basic-example-swg0y?file=/src/arrows.tsx) from the docs.